# Invoke-SqlCmd on Azure Runbook

Tags: azure, azure-runbook, invoke-sqlcmd

I'm trying to use the Invoke-SqlCmd cmdlet from a version 7.2 runbook to invoke a stored procedure. After installing the SqlServer module, and doing:

```
Import-Module sqlserver
Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance $serverName -Database 'data' -Query 'exec MyStoredProc'
```

I get the error:

> This module requires PowerShell 7.2.1+. Please, upgrade your
> PowerShell version by checking https://aka.ms/pscore6.
> System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: The term
> 'Invoke-SqlCmd' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function,
> script file, or executable program.

From what I can see, the max supported version of runbooks is 7.2. Am I missing something

Answer (score 1):

I also faced similar error to resolve this follow below steps:

- You can deploy [sqlserver module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SqlServer/21.0.17199)  via this page
  [image]
- Create runbook with **PowerShell version 5.1**
  [image]
- **My sample code:**

```sql
$SQL_Server_Name = Get-AutomationVariable -Name "servername"
$SQL_DB_Name = Get-AutomationVariable -Name "dbname"

$Query = "execute sp1"

invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance "$SQL_Server_Name" -Database "$SQL_DB_Name" -Username "username" -password "password" -Query "$Query" -Encrypt
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: so I can't run invoke-sqlcmd in powershell 7.2? it needs to be a runbook that's 5.1 @Pratik?

Comment: yes @AndrewDuffy when I ran command on runbook that's 5.1 PowerShell it run successfully.